# How to know whether a histogram holds more variance?

Tags: opencv, statistics, histogram, distribution

I was trying to identify bottle caps from an image. To do so, I need to know whether the histogram of hue distribution of detected circles(detected using houghcircles) are varied or densely populated on certain hue spectrum.

[image: all circles detected]

I already tried standard deviation, but, I don't know the number seems higher if the circle has more pixels. Is there a method to this?

How to know this histogram has varied hue?
[image: varied hue]

And this is not
[image: unvaried hue]

thanks!!

Comment: You can try a threshold on the entropy. Idk. Just a thought. BTW, you should use vertical bars on the plots, because they are not continuous.

Comment: I don't understand the question: a histogram does not hold variance

Comment: Hi @Cettt, sorry for my bad English, and terms I used maybe just wrong. what I want to achieve is filtering those bottle caps which has only one clustered hue(sorry if these are not the right words).
So, is there any method to know if the first histogram will not make to the selection, and the second will? Thanks!!